# Не выводит элемент объекта JSON

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(dataJson);
```

Дает результат: `{"UserChannelId":"cb4a62ba4af3ab722b599b270","title":"test"}`

и почему-то вот это: `console.log(dataJson.UserChannelId);`
дает результат: **undefined**

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: что дает `console.log(typeof dataJson)`

Comment: Дает string

Comment: В хроме всё работает

Comment: это node.js на сервере

Comment: если dataJson - string, тогда сделайте либо:

    dataJson = JSON.parse(dataJson);
    console.log(dataJson.UserChannelId);

либо копайте настройки того, кто вам эти данные вернул.

Comment: спасибо - помогло